# search inbetween text in file -python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to select and append only Filename ****D170322.H0**** with status sucess, in the file name till D same fixed letters no change and after D"current date".H0 .

we need to fetch file currentdate with "TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D+"current_date".H0

```
 Targetid                 Filename                           Date               STATUS
  1234       TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367          17-03-2022         SUCESS
  1234       TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H134367          17-03-2022         SUCESS
  1234       TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367          17-03-2022         ERROR
```

expected output :

```
   Targetid                 Filename                           Date               STATUS
      1234       TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367          17-03-2022         SUCESS
```

daily date change in file name ,below is the file format
today(mar-17)  = TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367   -
daily date upate in  after D (date) == D170322 ,
tomorrow(mar-18) = TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D180322.H034369

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output:                                                                                                                             Targetid                 Filename                           Date               STATUS
      1234       TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367          17-03-2022         SUCESS

Comment: When you say "current_date", do you mean the date in the `Date` column? or the date of today?

Comment: today(mar-17)  = TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367   -                                     
 daily date upate in  after D (date) == D170322 ,                                                
 tomorrow(mar-18) = TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D180322.H034367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean mask:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%d%m%y')
today = f'TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D{today}.H034367'

m = (df['Filename'] == today) & (df['STATUS'] == 'SUCESS')
out = df.loc[m]
print(out)

# Output
   Targetid                                Filename        Date  STATUS
0      1234  TRANNSS.FTRNONO.VCA579.D170322.H034367  17-03-2022  SUCESS
```